# Evaluate $\int_0^1 x^n \ln(1-x) \,\mathrm d x,$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I was trying to solve the  [Problem](http://www.mat.uniroma2.it/%7Etauraso/AMM/amm.html) 12207 of AMM.
If one considers $f \equiv 1$, then the problem reduces to

$$
\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{n}{\ln n}\int_0^1 x^n \ln(1-x) \,\mathrm d x.
$$

Now, I focused on the integral
$$
I_n := \int_0^1 x^n \ln(1-x) \,\mathrm d x,
$$
but I had some troubles:

- Integration by part does not work, since we obtain $\left(\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} \, \ln(1-x) \right)\Big|_0^1$, which is $-\infty$.
- Passing to Taylor series of logarithm does not work, since we obtain a divergent series.
- The substitution $x^n = t$ does not solve the problem, since we obtain $\frac{1}{n}\int_0^1 \sqrt[n]{t} \ln(1-\sqrt[n]{t}) \,\mathrm d t $

Do you have any other ideas to evaluate $I_n$?

Comment: $\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} \, \ln(1-x) $ is not the only term you obtain by using IBP

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1882555/the-integral-int-01-xn-log2-x-dx

Comment: @DatBoi sure, but it contains that piece that canno be evaluated, since it is not a finite value. Right?

Comment: @VIVID wow, thank you. I searched a lot but I did not find anything.

Comment: @SewerKeeper Why do you think it cannot be evaluated?

Comment: For IBP to "work", take $(x^{n+1}\color{red}{-1})/(n+1)$ as an antiderivative.

Comment: The solution section [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3772560/evaluate-the-sum-sum-m-n-geq-1-frac1m2nn2mkmn) can answer your query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $I_n$, it is known that (see [Is there a closed form for the integral $\int_0^1 x^n \log^m (1-x) \, {\rm d}x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1839100/is-there-a-closed-form-for-the-integral-int-01-xn-logm-1-x-rm-dx))
$$\int_0^1 x^n \log(1-x) \, {\rm d}x = -\frac{{H}_{n+1}}{n+1}\sim -\frac{\ln(n)}{n}$$
and therefore
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{n}{\ln n}\int_0^1 x^n \ln(1-x) \,d x=-1.$$